# This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-2010

I try to run android emulator in visual studio code, and got an error.

Here is my full error:

```
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code 1 during startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] ERROR   | This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
[ERR] ERROR   | ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.
```

I try to change SDK path in Android Studio from F: to E: which is my project is contain.

Comment: I have same Issue and I never found any soultion

The Android emulator exited with code -1073741515 during startup
Android emulator stderr:
Address these issues and try again.